# Change of variables PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given the equation $C\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + g(v − E) = \frac{a}{2R}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}$ where $C$, $g$, $E$, $a$, and $R$ are constants.  Let $w(y,z)=\frac{v(x,t)}{E}-1 $, $y=\frac{x}{A}$, and $z=\frac{t}{B}$.  What must $A$ and $B$ be in terms of the original constants such that $w$ satisfies $\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}+w =\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2}$ ?

Not sure how to start it. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the context for this problem? Is this from a class, or is this a personal study? It's often useful to know where a person is in math studies in order to provide an answer they can follow (and not do the work for them!).

Comment: This is for homework for a PDE class.

Comment: Are you sure of the form of $w(z,y)$?

Comment: I corrected that. I misread that part.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers
$$
\partial_t = \frac{dz}{dt}\partial_z = \frac{1}{B}\partial_z\\
\partial_x = \frac{dy}{dx}\partial_y = \frac{1}{A}\partial_y\\
\partial_{xx} = \frac{1}{A}\partial_y\frac{1}{A}\partial_y = \frac{1}{A^2}\partial_{yy}
$$
therefore your equation becomes
$$
C\frac{1}{B}\partial_z v(x,t) + g(v(x,t)-E) = \frac{a}{2R}\frac{1}{A^2}\partial_{yy}
$$
using $v = (w+1)E$ we find
$$
C\frac{1}{B}\partial_z v(x,t) + g((w+1)E-E) = \frac{CE}{B}\partial_z w + gEw = \frac{a}{2R}\frac{1}{A^2}\partial_{yy} = \frac{a}{2A^2R}E\partial_{yy}w
$$
thus we get
$$
\frac{CE}{B}\partial_z w + gEw =\frac{a}{2A^2R}E\partial_{yy}w
$$
we can factor out $E$ and divide through by $C/B$ we find
$$
\partial_z w + \frac{gB}{C}w = \frac{aB}{2A^2RC}\partial_{yy}w 
$$
so to achieve your desired result you need
$$
\frac{gB}{C} = 1\implies B = \frac{C}{g}\\
\frac{aB}{2A^2RC} = \frac{aC}{2gA^2RC} = 1\implies A = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2gR}{a}}
$$